# built-in [[Call]] and [[Construct]] algorithms understanding

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

> **9.3.1 [[Call]](thisArgument, argumentsList)**
>
> 10. Let result be the Completion Record that is the result of evaluating F in an implementation-defined manner that conforms to the
>     specification of F. thisArgument is the this value, argumentsList
>     provides the named parameters, and the NewTarget value is undefined.
>
> **9.3.2 [[Construct]](argumentsList, newTarget)**
>
> 10. Let result be the Completion Record that is the result of evaluating F in an implementation-defined manner that conforms to the
>     specification of F. The this value is uninitialized, argumentsList
>     provides the named parameters, and newTarget provides the NewTarget
>     value.

Can you explain to me what these proposals mean? I know what the `Completion Record` is. How to understand this part of the sentence: `result of evaluating F in an implementation-defined manner that conforms to the specification of F`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> result of evaluating `F` in an implementation-defined manner that conforms to the specification of `F`

The start, this line is in [section 9.3.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-built-in-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) and [section 9.3.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-built-in-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget). It is important to take the context into account here. If you look at [the summary of section 9.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-built-in-function-objects)

> The built-in function objects defined in this specification may be implemented as either ECMAScript function objects (9.2) whose behaviour is provided using ECMAScript code or as implementation provided function exotic objects whose behaviour is provided in some other manner. In either case, the effect of calling such functions must conform to their specifications.

That is the critical part. When your quoted line says "implementation-defined", it is referring to this here.

A function could for instance be implemented in C++ or any other language that the JS engine is executing on. All that is required is that the function perform the operation specified by the spec. It does not however have to be implemented in JS itself.

> If the specification describes this, then where is the description of the evaluation?

Since this section is about "builtin functions" the behavior here is any place where the spec defined behavior for JS function. For instance if we look at [section 17](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects) it states:

> Unless otherwise specified, each built-in function defined in this specification is created as if by calling the CreateBuiltinFunction abstract operation (9.3.3).

so any function defined in the spec has this implementation-defined behavior. For example [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object.prototype.hasownproperty) is implementation-defined. The steps are

> 1. Let P be ? ToPropertyKey(V).
> 2. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
> 3. Return ? HasOwnProperty(O, P).

but how those steps actually execute in the engine is unimportant as long as they happen.

Comment: Complicated. I do not understand there it is said that it depends on the specific implementation that describes the specification. What does it mean? If the specification describes this, then where is the description of the evaluation?

Comment: It seems to be understandable, but I still have to ask you. What does it mean: `result of evaluating F` (F is any function, this is clear) Where is described evaluation of function?

Comment: `F` in this case is any function defined by the spec, it does not include user-defined functions. The evaluation of the function is what I linked to for `hasOwnProperty`. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object.prototype.hasownproperty

Comment: That is, the evaluation of a function is an algorithm of a function that describes a specification, right?

Comment: The behavior of the function should behave, from the standpoint the executing JS code, exactly as the specification steps say.

Comment: evaluation of a function  - function algorithm described by the specification. That's what you're talking about, right?

Comment: For the builtin functions, which are the ones you're asking about, the function's behavior is defined by those steps in the spec.

Comment: I think so? Not sure I can answer that :P

Comment: Well, as far as I know the function call is provided by the [[Call]] internal method. In the 5th version of the specification, it was written: `Let's get the result of evaluating the FunctionBody that is the value of F's [[Code]] internal property. And you realize that this step performs the function code. If FunctionBody, then result is (normal, undefined, empty)` And you understand that this step performs the function code. In ES6 this is not. Where is it said that the function code is being executed?

Comment: The section you linked to is specifically for _builtin_ functions, which are the spec-defined functions, and have no `[[Code]]` because they aren't implemented with JavaScript. Arbitrary JS functions call behavior is defined in https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist

Comment: Hmm. I'm confused. If I understand correctly: there are functions that are not implemented in JS (functions that are written in the language on which the engine is written) and there are functions implemented through JS (these are functions defined by the user). But the functions defined by the user are understandable, since you can see where the content of the function is executing. And functions which are implemented not through JS are not clear, it is not visible where the function code executes. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I don't really follow what you mean by "clear" in this case. The spec very clearly defines how the non-JS functions work.

Comment: I mean where is written for the built-in functions of executing their code?
Just look how it looks like for ordinary functions http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinarycallevaluatebody

Comment: You have it in your question. Step 10 in https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-built-in-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist says "the result of evaluating F in an implementation-defined manner that conforms to the specification of F". That is the part that runs the algorithm for each builtin.

Comment: Even so? Did not know! For me, some parts of the specification are not obvious. Thanks for the help. P.S I want to ask a couple more questions about specification, I hope you can answer.